# How can I generate database automatically in symfony 4

Tags: symfony4

I'm trying to automatically create a database with Symfony 4. It would be enough to define a name for my database in a form and then my controller (or a service) automatically creates the database with that name and all tables with already created entities.

I'm using Symfony 4.2 and Mysql 5.7

My doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%default'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8mb4
                    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
            customer1:
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%customer1'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8mb4
                    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
            customer2:
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%customer2'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8mb4
                    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        default_entity_manager: gomyclic
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    Main:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Main'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Main'
                        alias: Main
            customer1:
                connection: customer1
                mappings:
                    Customer1:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity'
                        alias: Customer1
            customer2:
                connection: customer2
                mappings:
                    Customer2:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity'
                        alias: Customer2
```

The DATABASE_URL variable in .env

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://dbuser:dbsecret@127.0.0.1:3306/
```

And my actual code from my controller
The part who modify the doctrine.yaml file

```php
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput;

        $path = __DIR__ . '/../../config/packages/doctrine.yaml';
        $database_name = 'mydatabase';
        $file = Yaml::parseFile($path);
        $dbal = [
            "url" => sprintf("%%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%%%s", strtolower($database_name)),
            "driver" => "pdo_mysql",
            "server_version" => "5.7",
            "charset" => "utf8mb4",
            "default_table_options" => [
                "charset" => "utf8mb4",
                "collate" => "utf8mb4_unicode_ci"
            ]
        ];
        $orm = [
            "connection" => strtolower($database_name),
            "mappings" => [
                ucfirst(strtolower($database_name)) =>  [
                    "is_bundle" => false,
                    "type" => "annotation",
                    "dir" => "%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity",
                    "prefix" => "App\Entity",
                    "alias" => ucfirst(strtolower($database_name)),
                ]
            ]
        ];
        $file['doctrine']['dbal']['connections'][strtolower($database_name)] = $dbal;
        $file['doctrine']['orm']['entity_managers'][strtolower($database_name)] = $orm;
        $yaml = Yaml::dump($file, 8);
        file_put_contents($path, $yaml);
```

And the part who supposed to create the database and fulfill it with tables

```php
        $application = new Application($kernel);
        $application->setAutoExit(false);
        $input = new ArrayInput([
            'command' => 'doctrine:database:create',
            '--connection' => strtolower($database_name)
        ]);
        $output = new BufferedOutput();
        $application->run($input, $output);
        $content = $output->fetch();

        $application = new Application($kernel);
        $application->setAutoExit(false);
        $input = new ArrayInput([
            'command' => 'doctrine:schema:create',
            '--em' => strtolower($database_name)
        ]);
        $output = new BufferedOutput();
        $application->run($input, $output);
        $content = $output->fetch();
```

This will be so that we can create several databases on the same symfony application while having the possibility to create new ones without be forced to have to edit manually the doctrine.yaml file to create the new dbal and orm.

By running the code as it is now I get these 2 errors :

```
Error thrown while running command
"doctrine:database:create --connection=mydatabase"
. Message:
"Doctrine ORM Connection named "mydatabase" does not exist."
```

```
Error thrown while running command
"doctrine:schema:create --em=mydatabase"
. Message:
"Doctrine ORM Manager named "mydatabase" does not exist."
```

By looking for a solution on the internet i know i have to reinitialize the container but i didn't find a way to do it for my special case and i hope that there is another way to do this work with Symfony4 and Doctrine.

Answer (score 0):

You have created 3 Database Connections:

- default
- customer1
- customer2

And the error message shows you that "mydatabase" does not exist. True it is not configured. The doctrine:database:create looks for a configuration in your doctrine.yaml.

Therefore you would have to change the config dynamically, which is a huge security vulnerability.

Your use case looks like a perfect match for a [docker](https://knplabs.com/en/blog/how-to-dockerise-a-symfony-4-project) setup. With docker you could could create a base image with your desired functionality, then create a new dockerfile for your new database and then start up a new container.

For the startup script in each container there could be an sql script which initializes all tables as you want through [doctrine migration](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html).